# Extend jQuery with method, but return that method rather than jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guess this isn't jQuery specific, but it is involved in my example.. So I have extended jQuery in this style:

```
$.fn.extend({
    MyMethod : function(options = {}){
        return $(this).each(function(){
            // Code here
        });
    }
});
```

But.. if rather than returning the $(this) jquery object, I wanted to return the MyMethod method/class.. I thought I could do something like:

```
return arguments.callee
```

But unfortunately that doesn't either work with modern javascript, or wont work with strict mode.

Is there another way I can return that method?

Comment: Why would you want the method to return itself?

Comment: Why do you want to return the function here? Instead of  `arguments.callee` you should name your function `MyMethod : function MyMethod(){`  and then you could use `return MyMethod`.

Comment: So I could apply it to an element like: MyElement = $(".element").MyMethod();

And then use it's methods like MyElement.MyOtherMethod();

Comment: And what is `MyElement` in this case? It is not a function as you said in your question. So how is `arguments.callee` related to that?

Comment: @Zephni: Just returning the function reference won't achieve that. Why do that rather than using the same kind of chaining jQuery uses? It will be quite confusing to anyone coming to the codebase for there to bet **two** different kinds of chaining going on.

Comment: Fair point, was looking at this from the wrong angle. I have changed the whole way it works.. in other words it's not extending jQuery atall now

Answer (score 0):

It seems an odd thing to do. :-) But just give the function a name, which makes that name in-scope within the function; you can use that to return it:

```
$.fn.extend({
    MyMethod : function MyMethod(options = {}){
    // Name ------------^
        $(this).each(function(){
            // Code here
        });
        return MyMethod; // <== Return it
    }
});
```

Obsolete browsers had issues with that structure (called a *named function expression*), but modern ones don't.

Or for that matter, you could use the reference that's already accessible via `$.fn`:

```
$.fn.extend({
    MyMethod : function(options = {}){
        $(this).each(function(){
            // Code here
        });
        return $.fn.MyMethod; // <== Return it
    }
});
```